# Phonegap: download certificates and provisioning currently set

Tags: ios, cordova, certificate, phonegap, provisioning

There is a way to download the certificates and provisioning file **currently set** on the online phonegap builder ?

Thanks in advance.

Simon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

> Back up your signing keys, they cannot be retrieved from PhoneGap
>   Build after uploading under any circumstances.